# How to create a table with variable number of columns in itext7?

Tags: itext7

I'm trying to create a table that may have one to six columns, depending upon the data. If a column doesn't have any entries in any of the rows, the column should not be shown. So, one document may show the name, building and email columns and the next may show the name, email, telephone and office columns. For example, the empty columns outlined in pink should not be shown:

[image]

The only way I've found to create a table is to define the columns in the constructor. I tried setting the column width to zero but that didn't achieve the desired outcome. Can columns be added/removed after a table object is created?

**C#**

```
    Table table = new Table( new UnitValue[]
    {
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, 20F ),
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, columns.ContainsKey("Building") ? 20F : 0F ),     
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, columns.ContainsKey("Email") ? 15F : 0F ),
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, columns.ContainsKey("Telephone") ? 10F : 0F ),
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, columns.ContainsKey("Office") ? 10F : 0F ),
        new UnitValue( UnitValue.PERCENT, columns.ContainsKey("Note") ? 25F : 0F )
    }, true );
```

Comment: Why not building an array of column widths (`UnitValue[]`) dynamically and passing the array to the constructor afterwards? You can decide whether to add an entry to the array or not just like you do now: `columns.ContainsKey("Building")`.

Comment: @Alexey, good idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The iText team is slowly and methodically deprecating all the popular ways of setting up the columns in a Table! I suspect a conspiracy, but can't prove it ;-)

On a more serious note, it would be nice to know the philosophy behind some of these recent decisions. Are there plans for a super suite of tidy new APIs to handle this issue? Should we wait for some good news, or start complaining now?

With regard to Jim's issue, he is stuck between a rock and a hard place. Alexey is correct that the UnitValues should be set-up before the Table is ever created, but this code still assumes that columns get expanded to fill the available space. This is the way the old float-based Table constructor worked, and that has just been deprecated. This begs the question of how percentage column widths are treated, and that is neither documented nor guaranteed to remain the same in future releases. If I create a table with two columns, each of 25%, perhaps I want half the table to be blank. I don't see that it's iText's job to re-interpret my values, or try to "fix" them if I've made a mistake.

This is a well-known computing problem, and the common way to handle it is to allow a sentinel value in the list of column-widths which means "whatever's left". Then a percent array like say { 10%, -1, 10% } means two narrow columns either side of one 80% one. In Jim's case he knows how wide some of his columns need to be, but not the overall width, so he would do, say, 20% for Name, 10% for Number and -1 for the others, so they would get equal shares of whatever was left.

Comment: Hi @Vernon! Thanks for your opinion. When you mention this 25% issue, the way to get it work is to `setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(50))` to a table, and set equal percent widths to the columns. Are you aware of that option?

Comment: Hi @Alexey. Yes, I understand the APIs. I'm just trying to understand the philosophy behind them. For example, what is the behaviour when the percentages for the columns don't add to 100%? There seems to be an assumption the values will be adjusted in some way, but whilst that might seem sensible at first, I'm not sure that it is. And since the float[] constructor was recently deprecated, it suggests that relying on this behaviour would be wrong.